# Integrating a simpleSAMLphp IdP with a Shibboleth 2.2 SP

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, shibboleth

I'm new to SAML, but I'm tasked to integrate a website with a shibboleth 2.2 service provider.

Now simpleSAMLphp (the latest release) has configuration files for SAML 2.0 and Shibboleth 1.3.

But I thought Shibboleth was merely on implementation of SAML; I would not have thought the simpleSAMLphp side would have to be configured differently for a different SAML server; that would seem to defeat the point of a standard.

My hope is that Shibboleth 2.2 **IS** a standard SAML 2.0 implementation, and for Shibboleth 2.x, you would use the regular SAML2.0 configuration files in simpleSAML, rather than special shibboleth configuration.

But is that correct? If not, how do you configure simplesaml for shibboleth 2?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you use the "regular" SAML2 configuration.

Not sure what Shibboleth 1.3 did but it's classed as another identity protocols

"But also supports some other identity protocols, such as Shibboleth 1.3, A-Select, CAS, OpenID, WS-Federation and OAuth."